# many to many form:select, hibernate, spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have employees and services in a many to many. I create a service and when I choose to create an employee using the option selected those which would like to be able to assign the employee. My problem is that the jsp page I would like to see how many services have assigned to the employee but when I press save the service does not assigned to the employee. Here is my code. Thank you for your help.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Pattern(regexp = ".{2,40}", message = "invalid format")
    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Pattern(regexp = ".{2,40}", message = "invalid format")
    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{10})", message = "invalid format")
    @Column(name="MOBILE")
    private String mobile;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="Employee_MarketServiceRelation",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MARKETSERVICE_ID")})
    private List<MarketService> servicesList = new ArrayList<>();


    public List<MarketService> getServicesList() 
    {
        return servicesList;
    }

    public void setServicesList(List<MarketService> servicesList) 
    {
        this.servicesList = servicesList;
    }

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getFirstname() 
    {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) 
    {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() 
    {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) 
    {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getMobile() 
    {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) 
    {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getEmail() 
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) 
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getEmployeeId() + " " + getFirstname() + " " + getLastname() + " " + getMobile() + " " + getEmail();
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="MARKETSERVICE")
public class MarketService 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="MARKETSERVICE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer marketServiceId;

    @Pattern(regexp = ".{2,40}", message = "invalid format")
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
    @Column(name="PRICE")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "invalid format")
    @Column(name="DURATIONINMINUTES")
    private String durationInMinutes;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="servicesList")
    List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Employee> getEmployee() 
    {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(List<Employee> employee) 
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public Integer getMarketServiceId() 
    {
        return marketServiceId;
    }

    public void setMarketServiceId(Integer marketServiceId) 
    {
        this.marketServiceId = marketServiceId;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) 
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDurationInMinutes() 
    {
        return durationInMinutes;
    }

    public void setDurationInMinutes(String durationInMinutes) 
    {
        this.durationInMinutes = durationInMinutes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getMarketServiceId() + " " + getName() + " " + getPrice() + " " + getDurationInMinutes();
    }
}


@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> employeeList() 
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employee").list();
    }

    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) 
    {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Integer id) 
    {
        Employee employee = (Employee) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Employee.class, id);
        if (null != employee) 
        {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(employee);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void editEmployee(Employee employee) 
    {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(Integer employeeId) 
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Employee> list = session.createQuery("from Employee e where e.employeeId = :employeeId").setParameter("employeeId", employeeId).list();
        return list.size() > 0 ?(Employee)list.get(0): null;
    }
}


@Repository
public class MarketServiceDaoImpl implements MarketServiceDao
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<MarketService> marketServiceList() 
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from MarketService").list();
    }

    @Override
    public void addMarketService(MarketService marketService) 
    {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(marketService);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMarketService(Integer id) 
    {
        MarketService marketService = (MarketService) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(MarketService.class, id);
        if (null != marketService) 
        {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(marketService);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void editMarketService(MarketService marketService) 
    {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(marketService);
    }

    @Override
    public MarketService getMarketServiceById(Integer marketServiceId) 
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<MarketService> list = session.createQuery("from MarketService m where m.marketServiceId = :marketServiceId").setParameter("marketServiceId", marketServiceId).list();
        return list.size() > 0 ?(MarketService)list.get(0): null;
    }
}


@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService
{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;
    @Autowired
    MarketServiceDao marketServiceDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> employeeList() 
    {
        return employeeDao.employeeList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) 
    {
        employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);      
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmployee(Integer id) 
    {
        employeeDao.deleteEmployee(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void editEmployee(Employee employee) 
    {   
        employeeDao.editEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee getEmployeeById(Integer employeeId) 
    {
        return employeeDao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
    }
}


@Service
public class MarketServiceServiceImpl implements MarketServiceService
{
    @Autowired
    MarketServiceDao marketServiceDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<MarketService> marketServiceList() 
    {
        return marketServiceDao.marketServiceList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addMarketService(MarketService marketService) 
    {
        marketServiceDao.addMarketService(marketService);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteMarketService(Integer id) 
    {
        marketServiceDao.deleteMarketService(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void editMarketService(MarketService marketService) 
    {   
        marketServiceDao.editMarketService(marketService);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public MarketService getMarketServiceById(Integer marketServiceId) 
    {
        return marketServiceDao.getMarketServiceById(marketServiceId);
    }
}


@Controller
public class EmployeeController
{   
    //static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @Autowired
    private MarketServiceService marketServiceService;

    @RequestMapping({"/employee"})
    public String getEmployees(ModelMap map)
    {
        //logger.info("pobieram pracownikow");
        map.addAttribute("lists", employeeService.employeeList());
        return "employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNewEmployeeForm(ModelMap map)
    {
        map.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        map.addAttribute("lists", marketServiceService.marketServiceList());
        return "employeeForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployees(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="employee") Employee employee, BindingResult result)
    {
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "employeeForm";
        }

        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping({"/delete/{employeeId}"})
    public String deleteEmployees(@PathVariable(value="employeeId") Integer employeeId)
    {
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
        return "redirect:/employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/edit/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeForm(@PathVariable(value="employeeId") Integer employeeId, ModelMap map)
    {
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(employeeId);

        map.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "employeeForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/edit/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editEmployee(@PathVariable(value="employeeId") Integer employeeId, @ModelAttribute(value="employee") Employee employee)
    {
        employee.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
        employeeService.editEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/employee";
    }
}


@Controller
public class MarketServiceController 
{
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MarketServiceController.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @Autowired
    private MarketServiceService marketServiceService;

    @RequestMapping({"/marketService"})
    public String getMarketService(ModelMap map)
    {
        //logger.info("pobieram uslugi");
        map.addAttribute("lists", marketServiceService.marketServiceList());
        return "marketService";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/marketService/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNewMarketServiceForm(ModelMap map)
    {
        map.addAttribute("marketService", new MarketService());
        map.addAttribute("lists", employeeService.employeeList());
        return "marketServiceForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/marketService/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addMarketService(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="marketService") MarketService marketService, BindingResult result)
    {
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "marketServiceForm";
        }

        marketServiceService.addMarketService(marketService);
        return "redirect:/marketService";
    }

    @RequestMapping({"/marketService/delete/{marketServiceId}"})
    public String deleteMarketService(@PathVariable(value="marketServiceId") Integer marketServiceId)
    {
        marketServiceService.deleteMarketService(marketServiceId);
        return "redirect:/marketService";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/marketService/edit/{marketServiceId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMarketServiceForm(@PathVariable(value="marketServiceId") Integer marketServiceId, ModelMap map)
    {
        MarketService marketService = marketServiceService.getMarketServiceById(marketServiceId);

        map.addAttribute("marketService", marketService);
        return "marketServiceForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/marketService/edit/{marketServiceId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editMarketService(@PathVariable(value="marketServiceId") Integer marketServiceId, @ModelAttribute(value="marketService") MarketService marketService)
    {
        marketService.setMarketServiceId(marketServiceId);
        marketServiceService.editMarketService(marketService);
        return "redirect:/marketService";
    }
}


<table cellspacing='0'>

    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Table Header -->

    <c:forEach items="${lists}" var="employee">
        <tr>
            <td>${employee.firstname}</td>
            <td>${employee.lastname}</td>
            <td>${employee.email}</td>
            <td>${employee.mobile}</td>
            <td>${fn:length(employee.servicesList)}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/controller/delete/${employee.employeeId}"><img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/delete.png' />"></a>
                <a href="/controller/employee/edit/${employee.employeeId}"><img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/edit.png' />"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>


<form:form method="POST" commandName="employee">
    <table>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstname">FirstName</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" /> <form:errors
                    path="firstname" class="error_form" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname">LastName</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" /> <form:errors
                    path="lastname" class="error_form" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /> <form:errors path="email"
                    class="error_form" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="mobile">Mobile</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="mobile" /> <form:errors path="mobile"
                    class="error_form" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><form:label path="">Service</form:label></td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="servicesList" items="${lists}" multiple="true" />
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="image"
                src="<c:url value='/resources/images/save.png' />"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the solution, This code should be included in the controller.

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) 
    {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "servicesList", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class)
        {
            @Override
            protected Object convertElement(Object element)
            {
                Integer id = null;

                if(element instanceof String && !((String)element).equals("")){
                    try{
                        id = Integer.parseInt((String) element);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if(element instanceof Integer) {
                    id = (Integer) element;
                }

                return id != null ? marketServiceService.getMarketServiceById(id) : null;
            }
        });
    }
```